# Grails scaffolding link reference problem

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm using scaffolding for a couple of Controllers for two Domain Classes: 1 Sector to N Items:

```
class Item {

String name

static belongsTo = [sector:Sector]

....

}

class Sector {

String name

static hasMany = [items:Item]

....

}
```

When I generated the corresponding scaffolding controllers I used the pattern (class)mgr: Sectormgr.groovy and Itemmgr.groovy.

The problem is that some links are invalid in some of the generated views, for it is assuming the I followed the default names for the controllers. For instance:

- if I go to /sectormgr/show/20, the list of items associated with it have the link /item/show/22, instead of /itemmgr/show/22

Is there an easy fix for this? Am I missing something when I create the controllers ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways to address this I believe.  The simplest is to stick to Grails' convention of naming your controllers SectorController.groovy, ItemController.groovy, etc.

One other way to handle this that I *think* will work is to update your grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy.  Here is the default scaffolding:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                //apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

You want something like:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/${controller}mgr/$action?/$id?"{  //Add mgr after controller
            constraints {
                //apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to find out if this works for you.  Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URLMappings didn't seem to work for me, and it's a much more global change. Running `intall-templates` and changing the links to controllers in `src/templates/scaffolding/show.gsp` was the approach I took.

You'll need to restart your server after changing the template.